# Battery drops 20% after reboot!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery

Battery on Samsung Galaxy S2 on ICS likes to drop after reboot. Actually it happened when I was on Gingerbread as well. Anyone can help me fix this? Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Its likely because there's huge amount of R/W & CPU activity at the time of Reboot..

Comment: How do I find the culprit.?

Comment: I have the same problem. @SachinShekhar: This is obviously a bug. I've seen drops from 80% to 20% with just a reboot. No matter how R/W intensive boot might be, it doesn't explain this. Strange thing is, in my case reported battery capacity usually _increases_ after the reboot, without being connected to charger. But, though there is actually plenty power left, my phone will switch off Dropbox upload and misc sync, because it thinks battery's almost drained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no easy way in finding which process consumes your battery**. The battery monitoring tool in Android is not active during boot, so anyone wanting to know what's happening will have to make deep hackings in the Linux kernel and Android init scripts. I don't even believe you have a rooted phone or have a Android AOSP sources snapshot somewhere to hack into.

Also I believe that **the battery estimation mechanism is somehow fooled at startup**. Because it has no previous data to compare to (N is estimated depending on the value of N-1). So the level you see right after bootup is probably wrong. That's why you see the level strangely increasing although no power source was connected in the meantime. To what extent is this level wrong? Question without answer I think.

I have an easy solution though: stop installing apps that make your Android crash or need (stupid) reboot :-)